# "someone would give anything for something" vs "be dying"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '**would give anything**' and '**be dying**'? The definitions in Cambridge Online Dictionary:

- *someone would give anything for something*
  (also someone would give anything to do something): to want something very much
- *be dying*: To be dying to do something, or for something, is to be eager to do or to have it

Comment: They're both _hyperbole_ (obvious exaggeration) . Another version is 'I'd give my right arm for...'. I can't think of any particular difference in how they would be used.

Comment: If you take the phrases literally (which almost never happens), *dying* is one specific thing only, but *anything* involves both dying and everything else.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am British. I might, in suitable company, say "I'm dying for a piss", but I would not say "I would give anything for a piss".